# ARtoolkit setup for C++, everything is fine except the camera driver

Tags: windows-7-x64, artoolkit

Can't manage how to install VFW or WDM driver for my built in webcam, I got an acer 5920g running Windows 7 64-bit.

Following a guide, the last step is:

> ...You need also to test if the video input works and video can be displayed. You need to run the `videoTest` on the bin directory. if it's working (no error) a window video will be displayed (see figure below).This test confirms that your camera supports ARToolKit video module and ARToolKit graphics module.

The videoTest is an .exe and when I execute it it shows an error window telling :

> "It is impossible to start the program because MSVCP71D.dll doesn't
>   exists in the pc. To solve this problem try to reinstall the program"

I think it's something related to the VFW or WDM driver...isn't it? Any idea to make ARtoolkit works with my build in webcam?

Comment: The name ending in D means that it is a debug DLL, only available as part of Visual Studio 2003 (v7.1).

Answer (score -1):

[Try this link](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/fix-msvcp71-dll-and-msvcr71-dll-missing-error-in-windows-7/).  Those DLLs don't come with a default install of Windows (you would need Visual Studio 2003 to get them).

Comment: The link is about MSVCP71.dll, not MSVCP71D.dll. Totally different!